# Regex extract domain names from HTML

Tags: html, regex

I would like to extract domain names via Regex.

```
<option value=68385>domain1.com</option><option
 value=72737>domain2.com</option><option value=72739>domain3.com</option>
```

Comment: Isnt it easy to get domain names using jquery rather than regex?

Comment: Or even with pure JS, e.g. `document.querySelector('option').textContent`

Answer (score -1):

For these simpe domains, you can use belo RegEx

```
>([a-z0-9\.]+)<
```

But you need to split if from 1 to length-1

```
>domain1.com<
>domain2.com<    
>domain3.com<
```

Comment: That's what lookaheads/lookbehinds are for. Or you could just  put `()` around the part you want to match and then use that particular group instead of the whole match...

Comment: But it's depend on the programming language, tools and requirement. no?

Comment: Most regex engines support lookarounds, and pretty much all of them support groups